# Masstransit Analyzers

Tags: c#, masstransit, roslyn-code-analysis

In a brand new c# project
Using Masstransit.Analyzers nuget package (https://masstransit-project.com/learn/analyzers.html#message-initializers)

If i call `IPublishEndpoint.Publish<ISomeInterface>(new { random="fields"})`
as expected a message is generated

> Anonymous type is missing properties that are in the message contract 'ISomeInterface'. The following properties are missing: Name, Surname, etc,

If i create my own publisher using the decorator pattern

```
public interface IMyOwnPublishEndpoint{

  Task Publish<T>(object values, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
            where T : class;
}

public class MyOwnPublishEndpoint : IMyOwnPublishEndpoint
{
    private readonly IPublishEndpoint endpoint;
    MyOwnPublishEndpoint (IPublishEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }

 public async Task Publish<T>(object values, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
            where T : class
    {
        await endpoint.Publish<T>(values,cancellationToken )
    }

}
```

When i call `IMyOwnPublishEndpoint.Publish<ISomeInterface>(new { random="fields"})`

The same message does not get generated

Why is this the case?
Is perhaps the MassTransit Analyzer limited to a certain set of interfaces?

Comment: Had a quick look at the source code, and it seems its exactly the case (https://github.com/RemcoBlok/MassTransit.Analyzers/blob/master/src/MassTransit.Analyzers/CommonExpressions.cs) IsGenericInitializerMethod.
But don't understand why this limit,
Any workarounds?

Comment: The updated [source](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/develop/src/MassTransit.Analyzers). Also, there is no way around it, as MassTransit doesn't know you've created your own interface/method to publish messages.